# BizTalk BAM Excel "Unable to get resource string"

Tags: excel, biztalk, biztalk-bam, biztalk-2016, vba

When I click "BAM Activity" in Excel (2013 32-bit, running on Win 2008/R2 BT2016) I get one of two issues:

1) Variable not defined (on lvwTraces)

I tried solution from site below (changing Active-X trust settings), 
which sometimes get me past this to error #2, but sometimes not...

https://oussov.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/bam-xla-variable-not-defined-error-in-excel/

[image]

2) Unable to get resource string

I saw one posts about installing multi-language pack and setting language or region options.

http://vamsibiztalk.blogspot.com/2006/01/list-of-various-bam-questions.html

We are in the United States and not using any special language options.  Looks like the language pack was for people who need non-English?? 
My Control-Panel Region Settings shows English (United States).

I've never gotten past these errors to see the BAM menu.

When they talk about setting the language, I thought I would show my language settings in Excel here, as I'm not sure where else to set this, or if that is even the problem at all.
[image]

My Control Panel options are also set to English. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I must have accidentally changed the file, so went back to the original.

I started looking at the code and the errors, and looked like the variable/object "lvwTraces" was a list-view on the form that I might have unintentionally deleted.

I compared the file below, and noticed they were different sizes, so 
I copied From:
"c:\Software\BizTalk2016Dev\BizTalk Server\MSI\Program Files\ExcelDir\Bam.xla"
To: 
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Library\Bam_Backup.xla"